# What are the distinctions between the various WhenAny methods in Reactive UI

Tags: .net, reactiveui

There are several extension methods in Reactive UI for getting observables for property changes.

I think I understand `WhenAny` and `WhenAnyValue`.  `WhenAny` is for a series of property change notifications where you want the metadata of which object and property had the change, while `WhenAnyValue` is for when you really just want the stream of changed values.

First of all, is that an accurate assessment?

What about `WhenAnyDynamic`, `WhenAnyObservable`, and `ObservableForProperty`?  I can't really figure out what they're for, or how they're distinct from the first two.  Are they all intended for public use?  What is their purpose?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> I think I understand WhenAny and WhenAnyValue.

Let me demonstrate via code:

```
// These two statements are 100% identical, but the latter looks nicer.
this.WhenAny(x => x.Foo.Bar, x => x.Value)

this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Foo.Bar);
```

> What about WhenAnyDynamic, WhenAnyObservable, and ObservableForProperty?

`WhenAnyDynamic` is like WhenAny but when the things you want to observe aren't constants - you probably won't need it, but RxUI internals does.

`WhenAnyObservable` lets you get an Observable, but not have to worry about objects changing behind your back. For example

```
this.SomeChildViewModel.MyCoolCommand
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Clicked!"));

// Later...
this.SomeChildViewModel = new SomeChildViewModel();

// (Hey, why doesn't my Clicked! handler show up anymore! I'm still subscribed
// to the old object but it's super not obvious that's what happened)
```

Versus

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.MyCoolCommand).
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Clicked!"));

// Later...
this.SomeChildViewModel = new SomeChildViewModel();

// Cool, everything still works.
```

WhenAnyObservable is super useful in the **View** to Subscribe to Commands.

`ObservableForProperty` is like WhenAny but *doesn't* fire when initially subscribed to. You probably should ignore it, it's really just a building block for WhenAny that is around for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Should `this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.MyCoolCommand).` not be `this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.SomeChildViewModel.MyCoolCommand).`?

Comment: So you're saying that WhenAny(..).Skip(1) is preferable to ObservableForProperty(..) if I really only want change notifications? Is ObservableForProperty likely to be removed from a future version?